# multiple wordpress in one server with nginx

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I have one main wordpress app installed in this domain `test.wa-essence.com`,
now I want to setup a second wordpress under a subdomain `test.wa-essence.com/wachampionacademy`

the first wordpress in located inside `/var/www/test_wa_essence`
and the second wordpress is inside `/var/www/wa_champion`

I followed this instruction on setting the nginx https://serversforhackers.com/c/nginx-php-in-subdirectory

and here is the nginx config that I have written

```
server {
    root /var/www/test_wa_essence;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name test.wa-essence.com;

    location / {
           try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }

location /wachampionacademy {
    alias /var/www/wa_champion;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @nested;

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        }
}
location @nested {
        rewrite /wachampionacademy/(.*)$ /wachampionacademy/index.php?/$1 last;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }
    location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off; }
    location = /robots.txt { log_not_found off; access_log off; allow all; }
    location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
      expires max;
      log_not_found off;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.wa-essence.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.wa-essence.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
if ($host = test.wa-essence.com) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name test.wa-essence.com;
return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

I managed to install both wordpress by using different nginx config.
the first app can be accessed without any problem, however, `test.wa-essence.com/wachampionacademy` return me 404 eventhough it appears to be at the right wordpress app.

Please tell me what I got wrong in my nginx setup. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
server {
    root /var/www/wa_essence;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name test.wa-essence.com;

location /wachampionacademy/{
       try_files $uri $uri/ /wachampionacademy/?$args;
}

    location / {
           # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
           try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }
    location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off; }
    location = /robots.txt { log_not_found off; access_log off; allow all; }
    location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
      expires max;
      log_not_found off;
    }


}
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name test.wa-essence.com;

}
```

that is the final nginx config that I used,

however, the most important thing that I change I believe is the wordpress `siteurl` and `homeurl` to `test.wa-essence.com/wachampionacademy`